# Asymptotic growth rate of "int i=constant1; while(i < n) { i *= constant2; }"

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

What is the asymptotic growth rate of this function :

```
int i=3; 
while(i < n) {
   i *= 5; 
}
```

I measured it :

when `n=3` `i<n` is executed 1 time

.
.

when `n=16` `i<n` is executed 2 times

.
.

when `n=80`, `i<n` is executed 3 times

.
.

I need to find the right growth rate but I'm stuck.

Comment: Think about: What's the mathematical function this code implements? What is input (n?) and what is output (# of iterations?)?

Comment: Or, a more simple case: What's the growth rate if you had `i += 5` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the growth rate is:

```
3 * 5^x >= n
5^x >= n/3
```

therefore

```
xlog5 >= log n - log 3
x >= (log n - log 3) / (log 5)
```

You can define that `3*5^x` must be `>=n`. We can set up the equation in the first line with that basis.

Comment: Maybe a hint as to how to solve this homework would have been more beneficient to the OP...